# Interesting example of reintroducing a topology

Tags: functional-analysis

Is there an interesting example of an infinite dimensional Topological Vector Space whose topology was initially induced by something other than a norm or inner product and was latter found out to be a normed/inner product space?

Comment: Most Frechet spaces.

Comment: @QuantumSpace are they normable? Or just metrizable?

Comment: I suspect not many, if any... I'd be interested to see an example otherwise! For me, the way topologies arise is almost entirely by specifying a structure, and either demonstrating some form of completeness (to demonstrate the appropriateness of that topology), or taking a completion.